# Sample makefile for gcc

Tags: c, gcc, makefile

Is there any sample makefile project that only consists of .c and .h files?

I am using gcc, Windows 8.1

I found this, but it does not work:

```
#########################
# customise these
CFILES := sampleA.c main.c sampleB.
PROG := prog
CFLAGS := -Wall -Wextra -g
LDFLAGS :=
########################

# -MMD generates dependencies while compiling
CFLAGS += -MMD
CC := gcc

OBJFILES := $(CFILES:.c=.o)
DEPFILES := $(CFILES:.c=.d)

$(PROG) : $(OBJFILES)
        $(LINK.o) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^

clean :
        rm -f $(PROG) $(OBJFILES) $(DEPFILES)

-include $(DEPFILES)
```

I get the following error:

```
 undefined reference to sendto@24,socket@12,inte_addre@4, htons@04,bind@12, select@20,recvfrom@24, WSAGetLastError@0,WSAStartup@8,ioctlsocket@12
```

Comment: there are tons of makefile samples on the web

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#qscrl=1&q=makefile+c+sample&spell=1 first link

Comment: `sampleB.` looks nothing like a `CFILE`. perhaps a `.c` on the end may be of use.

Comment: What do you mean not working?  Any error message or it does not do what you expected?

Comment: After call make, i get a error `undefined reference to(sendto@24,socket@12,inte_addre@4, htons@04,bind@12, select@20,recvfrom@24, WSAGetLastError@0,WSAStartup@8,ioctlsocket@12`

Comment: If your `.h` files are in different directory. You're missing `-I` option for including `#include`.

Comment: Where must be this `I`?

Comment: @Seurabh Meshram: all files are in same direcotry

Comment: Have you inlcuded '#incude "sampleA.h"' and similarly sampleB.h in you C files ?

Comment: Is this C or C++ code? Is this code for linux/bsd or Windows?

Comment: @EtanReisner judging by the missing `WSA` points, I'm going out on a limb and suggesting it is a Windows console app and the OP neglected to link Ws2_32.lib with the final target.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer the below Makefile

```
exe ?= prog
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -g -Wall -Wextra -MMD
LDFLAGS =

all: $(exe)
$(exe) : sampleA.c sampleB.c main.c
         $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^ -o $@

clean: 
        -rm $(exe)
```

Here `prog` is output executable at the end of make.

Comment: Same problem: `undefined reference to(sendto@24,socket@12,inte_addre@4, htons@04,bind@12, select@20,recvfrom@24, WSAGetLastError@0,WSAStartup@8,ioctlsocket@12`

Comment: @staigoun, Are you sure, you're not missing some definition in your code ? Does `gcc -o prog -g -Wall -Wextra -MMD sampleA.c sampleB.c main.c` work ?

Comment: Yes, it work, but if i try `make` i get a `undifined reference to` error

Comment: @staigoun That is strange, what make internally does is execute that command. Double verify whether `gcc -g -Wall -Wextra -MMD sampleA.c sampleB.c main.c -o prog` works without any issue.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing some required library, `wsock32` and `ws2_32` if I'm not mistaken.

Use this Makefile:

```
EXE :=  prog.exe
SRC :=  $(wildcard *.c)
OBJ :=  $(SRC:.c=.o)
DEP :=  $(OBJ:.o=.d)

CC          :=  gcc
CPPFLAGS    :=  -MMD -MP
CFLAGS      :=  -W -Wall -g
LDFLAGS     :=
LDLIBS      :=  -lwsock32 -lws2_32

.PHONY: all clean fclean re

all: $(EXE)

$(EXE): $(OBJ)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $^ $(LDLIBS) -o $@

clean:
    $(RM) $(OBJ) $(DEP)

fclean: clean
    $(RM) $(EXE)

re: fclean all

-include $(DEP)
```